# libcouchbase on ubuntu 14 errors

Tags: libcouchbase

I cloned https://github.com/couchbase/libcouchbase and checkout to version 2.5.8. After that I compiled it as in the documentation from the git page

```
$ git clone git://github.com/couchbase/libcouchbase.git
$ cd libcouchbase && mkdir build && cd build
$ ../cmake/configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

Afterwords, I installed couchbase from pip: 

`sudo pip3 install couchbase`

But when I do:
python3 -c 'import couchbase'
I've got

    `import couchbase._libcouchbase as C
ImportError: libcouchbase.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I made a link in /usr/lib/libcouchbase.so.2 to /usr/local/lib/libcouchbase.so.2

`sudo ln  -s /usr/local/lib/libcouchbase.so.2 /usr/lib/libcouchbase.so.2`

but now I get 

    `import couchbase._libcouchbase as C
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/couchbase/_libcouchbase.cpython-34m.so: undefined symbol: lcb_n1x_list`

Linux version:

`cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS \n \l`

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You're encountering this error because your version of libcouchbase is not recent enough to correspond to your version of the Couchbase Python SDK. The current version of the Couchbase Python SDK (2.0.9) requires libcouchbase>=2.6.0.

You have two options to handle this:

- Use an older version of the Couchbase Python SDK
- Update to the newer version of libcouchbase

Using an older version of the Python SDK is easily done with pip:

```
$ sudo pip3 install couchbase==2.0.8
```

Installing a newer version of libcouchbase would be similar to the procedure you've already taken, except you would of course need to checkout version 2.6.0.

That being said, it is generally recommended to use the official builds distributed on the Couchbase website. You can either download tars from the libcouchbase [downloads page](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.1/sdks/c-2.4/download-list.html) or add the [official Couchbase repositories](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/sdks/c-2.4/download-install.html) and `apt-get install` libcouchbase.